# Any anomaly detection algorithm does not require pre-determined anomaly percentage?

Tags: anomaly-detection

Most common anomaly detection algorithms that I know of (e.g., OneClass SVM) require that one estimates the percentage of anomalies in the dataset; e.g., 1%, o.1%, etc. Then it lists the top 1% (or 0.1%, etc.) highest scores from the output and classify them as anomalies. In some situations, one may not be able to accurately estimate the percentage.

Are there algorithms that do not require pre-determined anomaly ratios?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [IsolationForest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html) and set `contamination=0.0`.
Another alternative is an [Autoencoder with reconstruction error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder#Anomaly_Detection).
In both cases the assumption is that there is practically no anomalies in your training set. You should look at your anomaly scores and set your threshold based on your requirements.